# replace date value in the field in delimited file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file (`ph.lst`) which contains below records. I need to remove the number which comes after `.txt`. That number is generated randomly so we cannot expect the same on all the time.

```
test_wkly_20200428010453_PD.txt.1589553864|test_wky|05-01-2020 16:07:53|35858
```

I want remove `.1589553864` and my output should be

```
test_wkly_20200428010453_PD.txt|test_wky|05-01-2020 16:07:53|35858
```

I have tried
`sed -i 's/\.[0-9]$*//' ph.lst`

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `sed` command:

```
sed -i 's/txt\.[0-9]*/txt/' ph.lst
```

Replaces `txt.` followed by any amount of numbers with `txt`.

Comment: thanks its worked

Answer (score 0):

The command that you say you have tried,

```
sed -i 's/\.[0-9]$*//' ph.lst
```

is only a *tiny* bit wrong.  The `$` would match the end of the line, but this is not what you want to match at that point.  Instead, use

```
sed 's/\.[0-9]*//' ph.lst
```

or,

```
sed 's/\.[[:digit:]]*//' ph.lst
```

This would delete every digit that occurs directly after the first dot (and the dot) on each line of input. The output would be written to standard output, so you can redirect it into a new file.

With `awk`, you would do the same sort of thing with

```
awk -F '|' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { sub("\.[[:digit:]]*", "", $1) }; 1' ph.lst
```

This parses the lines of `ph.lst` as `|`-delimited fields and removes the substring using same regular expression as with `sed` (here only acting on the first field).